# core.async go block with outside bound symbols works but does not macroexpand

Tags: clojure, thread-safety, threadpool, clojurescript, core.async

for the past few weeks I’ve been working with “core.async” in Clojure and Clojurescript, wondering if it is a good idea to use outside bound symbols inside a `go` as there is a pool of threads and possibly any of these could use the bound symbols. It works evaluating it, but macroexpansion does not work - see the following snippets

I guess it should work without problems. The `x` is immutable and wont change by concurrent threads. Using an `atom` as `x` for mutable data should also work cause its an `atom` XD E.g. an object ref would not work of course or could make problems!

```clj
(let [x 5]
  (clojure.core.async/go
   (println x)))

;; => 5
;; nil
```

```clj
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all
   '(let [x 5]
      (clojure.core.async/go
        (println x))))

;; => Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core.async/go at (your_project.cljc:93:3).
;;    Could not resolve var: x
```

It seems to work, but is it a bad idea and why?

Anyone can explain why macroexpansion does not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`macroexpand-all` is not a high-fidelity expander. It uses a basic process that works for simple macros, but it doesn't do everything the actual compiler does. Notably, it does not curate the `&env` map that bindings should introduce. I assume core.async needs to look at `&env` to determine whether a binding is local or a var.

So, you shouldn't expect `macroexpand-all` to work here, but there's nothing wrong with writing code of this sort.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you known an article about the differences of compiler expansion and macroexpand?

Comment: I donl't think anyone has written that article. The way to know the difference is to (1) fully understand how the actual compiler macroexpands, and (2) compare that to the source of `macroexpand-all`, which does something very simple.

Comment: so where do you got the info from source code or some docs about compiler or something else?

Comment: It's pretty easy to find the compiler source on github. Reading it is not trivial, of course, but no knowledge comes for free. TBH my own knowledge of it is somewhat out of date - I haven't really kept up since they added clojure.spec, and apparently macros with specs have changed the compiler steps.